# How can I modify stacked bar chart in ggplot2 to show actual values instead of proportions?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to recreate this kind of chart in ggplot2. How can I draw it?
My data is

```
NEP <- tibble::tribble(
                 ~Age, ~Level_in_Old_Education_Policy, ~Level_in_NEP_2020,
                   3L,                             NA,     "Foundational",
                   4L,                             NA,     "Foundational",
                   5L,                             NA,     "Foundational",
                   6L,                      "Primary",     "Foundational",
                   7L,                      "Primary",     "Foundational",
                   8L,                      "Primary",      "Preparatory",
                   9L,                      "Primary",      "Preparatory",
                  10L,                      "Primary",      "Preparatory",
                  11L,                      "Primary",           "Middle",
                  12L,                      "Primary",           "Middle",
                  13L,                      "Primary",           "Middle",
                  14L,                    "Secondary",        "Secondary",
                  15L,                    "Secondary",        "Secondary",
                  16L,                    "Secondary",        "Secondary",
                  17L,             "Higher Secondary",        "Secondary",
                  18L,             "Higher Secondary",        "Secondary"
                 )
```

The desired chart looks like the following:
[image: Changes in education policy]

For this, I tried to create a stacked bar chart, as Yacine has suggested. But now there is one minor issue. My code is as follows:

```
NEP_Long <- NEP %>% select(Age,Old = Level_in_Old_Education_Policy,New = Level_in_NEP_2020) %>% pivot_longer(cols = 2:3,names_to = "Education_Policy",values_to = "Values")
NEP_Long %>% ggplot()+geom_bar(aes(x = Education_Policy, fill = Values),position = "fill", stat = "count")
```

But now, on the y-axis, I am finding some proportions, instead of actual ages. How can I change the code so that it shows actual age (e.g., 3 or 6) instead of values like 0.25?

Comment: I don't it is possible without calculating all polygons making up the cube edges in isometric projection yourself. I don't know of any functions that would help with this. You might be able to represent this as a stacked bar chart though.

Comment: You can start with 2D stacked barplots with proportions. Or as said by teunbrand, create it manually and display it on plot_ly.